# method in focusout execute once

Tags: ajax, jquery

hi i have a jquery function that it has ajax method , when focus out of the text box function must fire. i have a server side button in ajaxpanel but when i press the button and button operation do properly then  never execute focus out

```
    jQuery("#drpProvider").focusout(function () {
        var x;

        var customer = 1;
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "request.aspx/branchsafed",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({

                customer: customer

            }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (ret) {
                var specification = ret.d;

                if (ret.d == "no") {

                }
                else {

                    var temp = ret.d;
                    $("#blocklable").text(temp);

                }

            }
        });


    });
```

Comment: Can you paste your html code?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="title">
```

javascript:

```
$('#title').focusout(function() {
if( $(this).val() ) {
    alert('!!');
    $(this).unbind('focusout');
} 
});
```